# Show "Wait" message while performing an action

Tags: c#, popup

I have a function which takes about 5 seconds to complete and I would like to show a "Wait" message while the function is running.

Here's my code:

```
if (puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia.Count == 4)
{
    generar_puntos_rectangulo_por_imagen(); //This takes 5 seconds
}
```

How can I show a pop up window with the text "Wait"? I tried a messagebox but my function doesn't run until the user clicks "OK" so there has to be another way to do this..

```
private void generar_puntos_rectangulo_por_imagen()
{
    Point Inicial_izquierdo_inf = new Point(puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[0].X, puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[0].Y);
    Point Inicial_derecho_sup = new Point(puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[1].X, puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[1].Y);
    Point Final_izquierdo_inf = new Point(puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[2].X, puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[2].Y);
    Point Final_derecho_sup = new Point(puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[3].X, puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia[3].Y);

    puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia.Clear();
    int wu = 24;

    for (int i = 0; i < img.Count; ++i)
    {
        // Time consuming calculations
    }
}
```

Comment: Winforms? Check this out [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: My only problem with this approach is that I have 3 or 4 time consuming functions so I would need to create 3 or 4 background workers for each, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new form into your project and write `Wait` on it, and then show that form whenever you need to show wait message to user.

For example your new form name is `PopUp`. Create its instance before that method, and dispose it later:

```
if (puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia.Count == 4)
{
    PopUp popup = new PopUp(); //create instance
    popup.Show(); //display popup

    generar_puntos_rectangulo_por_imagen(); //This takes 5 seconds

    popup.Dispose(); //close popup
}
```

**Additional:**

You can also update the message shown. Create a method in `Popup` class:

```
public void SetMessage(string message)
{
    this.lblMessage.Text = message;
}
```

Invoke:

```
if (puntos_rectangulos_estereotaxia.Count == 4)
{
    PopUp popup = new PopUp(); //create instance
    popup.SetMessage("Wait ! It'll take few seconds to complete."); //set message
    popup.Show(); //display popup

    generar_puntos_rectangulo_por_imagen(); //This takes 5 seconds

    popup.Dispose(); //close popup
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I can get rid of the maximize/minimize buttons on this new form as well as tweak it (center it etc). Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: You can also change message while displaying. I've added a bit more explanation to the answer.